# Is it possible to mock a statement using Mockito in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

Say,

I have a method getTemplateData() and I want to mock a restTemplate.exchange() method call in that

```
public List<String> getTemplateData(String templateId, String storeId, String projectId) {
          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          Map<String, String> bodyObject = new HashMap<>();
          bodyObject.put("functionalAreaId", templateId);
          bodyObject.put("storeId", storeId);
          bodyObject.put("projectId", projectId);
          HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyObject, null);
          ResponseEntity<List<String>> result =
              restTemplate.exchange(
                  BaseUrl + "/template",
                  HttpMethod.POST,
                  requestEntity,
                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {});
          List<String> screens = result.getBody().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
          log.info(
              "Completed executing the method getTemplateData for the templateId:{} and storeId:{}",
              templateId,
              storeId);
          return screens;

      }
```

I want to mock the line

```
ResponseEntity<List<String>> result =
              restTemplate.exchange(
                  BaseUrl + "/template",
                  HttpMethod.POST,
                  requestEntity,
                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {});
```

Is it possible to mock a statement in Java?

Comment: The statement should be extracted to method, in your case something like `createResponseEntity`, then you can mock the intermediate method in order to return mockup of `ResponseEntity`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be mocked.

```
@Test
public void test() {
   // let's create mock first, you can use annotation also
   RestTemplate mockTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);

   Mockito.when(mockTemplate.exchange(Mockito.eq(BaseUrl + "/template"),
              Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
              Mockito.eq(requestEntity),
              Mockito.any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))
          .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(Arrays.asList("data"), HttpStatus.OK))
}
```